# no visible interface for UILabel declares the selector objectAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c

Racking my brain around this one. Ive got my tableview item linked up to the secondviewcontroller. I am trying to get my data to transition over to the label when I click an item in the tableview. I am getting an error in my prepareforsegue code though. The line that is giving me issues is:

**destViewController.toDoItemName = [toDoItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];**

objectAtIndex is defined in my ViewController but not in my SecondViewController as it doesnt need to be. How would I make this connection?

The entire source is here: https://github.com/martylavender/LittleToDoApp/tree/Storyboards

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize toDoItem;
@synthesize toDoItemName;
@synthesize tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    toDoItem.text = toDoItemName;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
         if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
         SecondViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         destViewController.toDoItemName = [toDoItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are performing a method on a UILabel that does not exist. The method `objectAtIndex:` is available on NSArray and similar objects, but not on UILabel.

It seems to me that you are attempting to get the contents of the label on the selected UITableViewCell.

If so, you could get the contents of the label of the cell as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        SecondViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        destViewController.toDoItemName = cell.textLabel.text;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Also, your `prepareForSegue:` code should be in the implementation of the UIViewController that gets you to the SecondViewController, not in the implementation of the destination view controller, as it is here.

Comment: So I should end up with something like this:

      - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {  

     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDoItemCell"]) {  

         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];  

         destViewController.toDoItemName = cell.textLabel.text;  
          
}  
     
}  

Sorry I cant seem to add line breaks in my comment back

Comment: I edited it to clarify what I meant. Is this what you're trying to do? Get the text from the label on the selected cell?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do.  

On my main ViewController I input  text. It saves. I click on the text in the cell and it loads the SecondViewController which has a single label. That label should output the text from the selected cell in the main ViewController

Comment: Great, well, give what I put up there a shot and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok  changed the prepare for seque code. no errors in my code but i still end up with a blank label when the SecondViewController shows up.

Comment: Move that prepareForSegue method from your SecondViewController.m file to your ViewController.m file. You want to prepareForSegue before you go to a vc, not after you've arrived. I'll edit again to explain.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. Now getting this:  'unknown receiver 'tableView' did you mean 'UITableView' which doesnt make sense to me as tableView is linkd up in ViewController.h

Comment: No, I meant `tableView`. You didn't `@synthesize` the tableView in your ViewController.m, which is fine, you can still reference it by `self.tableView`. You should probably spend some time really thinking about your models and views and trying to determine why and where you want certain attributes to be. And learn about your objects, take your time, programming in new languages is not meant to be learned in a day. :)